# Getting a sum of only the first instance of a column in a sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL code:

```
SELECT EmployeeID,
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN Error1 = '0'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END + CASE 
            WHEN Error2 = '0'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END + CASE 
            WHEN Error3 = '0'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS TotalErrors
FROM SubmittedDocuments
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```

The statement should calculate the number of errors in the table for each employee.  However, there is another column in the table SubmittedDocuments named "DocumentName".  How could I write a statement that only counts errors for the first instance of each DocumentName?  (Or only counts for the one with the lowest "SubmittedID", the unique identifier)

Sorry if anything in unclear, I will attempt to clear up any confusion in the comments.

Comment: Does a group by on DocumentName not work?

Comment: Help us reproduce your scenario. Add some basic DML and DDL to your question so we have data to work with. Possibly create a [companion sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for your question (put all relevant code in the question too though!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might have not got this right from your question, but I think this should work. If you could show some sample data and expected output then we can definitely have a sure answer.

```
SELECT EmployeeID
    SUM(CASE WHEN DocIDErr > 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
FROM
(SELECT EmployeeID
   , Error1
   , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY DocumentName) AS DocIDErr
FROM SubmittedDocuments) AS RS
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```

Comment: Thank you, that gave me the information needed to solve it for me.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want aggregation.  I think you just want to select the first document for each name.

If so, this may be what you want:

```
select sd.*,
       ((case when error1 = '0' then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when error2 = '0' then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when error3 = '0' then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as numerrors
from (select sd.*,
             row_number() over (partition by documentname order by submittedid) as seqnum
      from SumittedDocuments sd
     ) sd
where seqnum = 1;
```